# Advantage of distinguishing LWE using short vector in dual lattice

Tags: lwe

In analyzing the advantage of distinguishing LWE via dual attack, many papers uses the result of [[LP11]](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ecpeikert/pubs/lwe-analysis.pdf) as follows :

> Given an LWE instance parameterized by $n$, $\alpha$, $q$ and a vector
> $\mathbf{v}$ of length $||\mathbf{v}||^2$ in the scaled dual lattice
> $L = \{\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{Z}^m_q| \mathbf{w} \mathbf{A} ≡ \mathbf{0} \mod q\}$, the advantage of distinguishing
> $\left<\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{e}\right>$ from random is close to
> $exp{(−π{({||\mathbf{v}||}_2 \cdot \alpha)}^2)}$.

However, [LP11] does not provide any proof that the above statement is true.

I tried to derive it with Lemma 2.2 in [LP11] but I failed.

Does anyone know how to derive the advantage?